# Best environment to play with Chef automation framework Ubuntu or Mac?

Tags: chef-infra

I am working as a Dev-ops engineer and having experience in Chef.
My working environment is Ubuntu, I know the steps about set up Chef server, workstation and client in ubuntu flavor.
And also I developed lot of cookbooks for ubuntu and centos servers.

Now I would like to move Mac environment, I know the commands were available for this Mac OS.
But I got some suggestion Ubuntu in best environment to play with Chef, not that much in Mac.

is it right? anyone please suggest which is best for chef process like Ubuntu or Mac ?

Advance in Thanks
Ganesan.A

Comment: Opinion based, take the Os you're more comfortable with. And please avoid cross posting here and on mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS as workstation is totally fine. Chef-client also allows you configure MacOS. Only Chef-Server is Linux-only.